# Expression for 1-DOF Rotational System

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering

I am trying to build a system in which a servo motor controls the angle of a platform through a linkage.

The servo arm, linkage, and platform connection have fixed lengths $S, L, H$ respectively The servo arm rotates about a point offset $-B$ from the point of fixture of $H$. I have control over the servo angle $\theta_s$ and wish to derive an expression for the control platform angle, $\theta_c$.

I have attached a diagram.

Thanks in advance for any help.[image]

Comment: What methods have you tried so far? Please also [edit] into the question the attempts made so far and where you became stuck. Please label the corner points in the diagram to make it easy to label angles. If a line $A$ is drawn from the top node of the red link to the origin, we should be able to calculate its length using cosine formula since we know the included angle $\theta_s$ of the sides $\overline B$ and $\overline S$. This should allow you to calculate the angles in the triangle $LHA$. This should allow for the calculation of $\theta_c$.

Comment: [Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines).

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40570/how-can-i-simulate-this-toggle-mechanism/45304#45304

Comment: @joojaa that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much